# mongoDB document level locking

Tags: mongodb

Looks like 3.0 version has support for Document level locking, but it is still dev phase,when is the production release is planned?

We want to use to generate Ids for some our collections. So if there was a provision for the Document level mapping the performance would have been better.

Comment: It's worthwhile to note that document level locking will be available only using the WiredTiger storage engine. The original MongoDB storage engine (now called MMAPv1) now supports *collection*-level locking. WiredTiger won't be the default storage engine in 3.0 but from 3.2.

Comment: The default `_id`s are typically generated by your driver, so server-side locking granularity is likely irrelevant for performance of `_id` generation. If you have a performance question you should be asking about that (with specific details).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about a product release date (one that's already occurred, as well), and not directly a programming question.

Comment: Good article on lock-level & sharding [link](http://www.arborian.com/2016/03/11/mongodb-mmapv1-wiredtiger-and-queues/)

Answer (score 0):

Early March according to the announcement: http://blog.mongodb.org/post/109975522923/announcing-mongodb-3-0